# Cleanup old artifacts from Jfrog artifactory OSS

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang, jfrog-cli

I'm using Jfrog artifactory OSS version 5. I can see my snapshot repository is too huge and I want to remove unwanted artifacts from snapshot repository.

I want to remove all artifacts which were not downloaded during last 6 months.
I tried below method, but its not working seems because of I'm using OSS version.

`curl -X POST -v -u user:'password' "http://<my artifactory url>/artifactory/api/execute/cleanup?params=months=6|repos=snapshots|dryRun|paceTimeMS=2000"`

Is there any other way that I can perform my task and if somebody can help me to do this, it would be really appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JFrog's CLI to delete items based on AQL queries.

---

For example, you can use an AQL query like:

```
items.find({"created" : {"$before" : "6mo"}})
```

To find all items that were created over 6 month ago.

You can then use your AQL as part of a spec file for deleting items and artifacts, using the JFrog CLI.

---

- To read more about the AQL [Time Operators](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-RelativeTimeOperators)
- To read more about [CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DeletingFiles) and File Specs

Comment: Thanks my friend. I also found out that we could find files which have not been download for few month. hope this may be helpful for some other one.

Answer (score 0):

```
items.find (
    {
             "repo":"snapshots",
             "stat.downloads":{"$eq":null}
    }
```

)

This will search for file which have not been downloaded ever, under repository name "snapshots"